# What would be the effects of a -1000 nanotesla geomagnetic storm be on modern electronics?

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism, magnetics, physics

After reading the [Wikipedia article on geomagnetic storms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_storm#Occurrences), I'm curious about what the effects of a -1000-nanotesla-minimum geomagnetic storm would be on modern military and consumer electronics, as well things like satellites, radar, and power grids.

The [March 1989 geomagnetic storm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_1989_geomagnetic_storm), with a minimum of -589 nT, shut down Quebec's power grid, but the [Bastille Day event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastille_Day_event), with a minimum of -301 nT, apparently didn't do much, at least to power grids. The -1600-nanotesla [Carrington event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrington_Event#:%7E:text=The%20Carrington%20Event%20was%20a,largest%20geomagnetic%20storm%20on%20record.&text=The%20storm%20created%20strong%20auroral,serious%20damage%20to%20telegraph%20systems.) made telegraph poles throw sparks. However, I cannot find information on how either affected military/consumer electronics, especially given that the latter did not occur when electricity was really a thing.

What would a -1000 nT storm cause, and how could it be shielded against?

Comment: Just wondering, why are all your nT values negative?

Comment: @Transistor The Wikipedia article on geomagnetic storms uses the disturbance-storm time index to measure geomagnetic storms. A negative value means the Earth's magnetic field is weakened. See https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/what-is-the-meaning-of-integral-of-negative-magnetic-field-nt-over-time?rq=1.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE Even a small amount of Teslas, given enough area, leads to a unimaginable Webers (magnetic charge, so to speak.) Well, it is imaginable. A quick calculation that assumes a solar flare covers the entire earth's facing surface towards the sun suggests that -1000 nT corresponds to over 100 million Webers! 10^8!. That's a heck of a lot of magnetic charge!! Of course, the entire thing is dynamic and in continual state of change, which is the real problem I suppose. It would be the rapid expansion of open flux in the magnetosphere that has to be a key! Interesting question. +1

Answer (score -1):

Why do you think there will be any effect? - 1000nT is far less than the magnetic fields from magnets and transformers. It is only large-scale objects (miles) that see effects.

CRTs can be affected but they are largely obsolete. Colour televisions were even affected by the earth's field (~50nT) and required degaussing if moved.

Comment: Even a small magnetic field change, over hundreds of kilometers of cable, can induce *huge* voltages. See the link in the question, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrington_Event .

Comment: @DrMoishePippik you won't find hundreds of miles of cable inside consumer electronics.  the question was not about damage to the grid.

Comment: "things like satellites, radar, and power grids." in the question, so large scale is relevant.